# Bash script to restart app

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

Can you help me to create *bash* (or *sh*) script, which will start application (`./newserver`) and every hour will kill this application (send signal) and start again.

Also it should check whether application is working and if not - restart, for cases when application crashes and etc.

For linux ubuntu

Comment: Under which OS are you running your script (I'm asking that to deduce the options your "at" command will have)

Comment: Why? is it a buggy server? servers are not supposed to be killed

Comment: Your question is too narrow for SO. Answers posted here are intended to help others that have similar problems. Here you more or less ask people to do the whole job for you.

Comment: @SkippyFastol thank for you answer. On Ubuntu Linux

Comment: BTW, have a look at the `cron` daemon, it should do your hourly business. The rest of your request is just writing commands in a row in a script file.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper, thanks for your answer. But how how cron will find needed process id? When i start process via sh script, it suspends while process is working and it cant write pid somewhere

Comment: write it in a default file when the app is lauched (that's the technique used by most daemons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have already pointed out, this is not the best way to handle whatever's wrong with your script. However I'll assume you have special reasons for needing this.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
   ./newserver &
   pid=$!
   sleep 1h
   kill -n 9 $pid
done
```

As for checking whether or not it's working you'll have to create some analytics to identify this. I don't know anything about your script but I doubt you'll want to try to do that in bash.

Unless by "working" you just mean running, in which case

```
#!/bin/bash
run_server () {
  while :; do
    ./newserver &
    pid=$!
    sleep 1h
    kill -n 9 $pid
  done
}
run_server &
while :; do
  if [ "$(kill -n 0 $pid 2>&1)" ]; then
    run_server &
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your server start up script in `/etc/inittab` init will spawn it if it die.